# Prevent multiple queued POSTs on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

For example, when user clicks a button, the server sends a div that is then appended to the body, but there's no logic that prevents the user to queue POSTs untill none has completed.

This then leads to the problem that it is ignoring the logic that only one of that div may exist, appending multiples at once once the queued POSTs are completed.

How can I prevent this problem?

Div sent from server :

```
'<div id="test_div"></div>'
```

Button event :

```
$('body').on('click', '#test_button', function(){
    $.post('get_test_div/',function(response){
        //The following if is ignored if there are uncompleted queued POSTs
        if($('#test_div').length < 1){
            $('body').append(response);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @MattSpinks edited with better wording

Comment: Is the problem that one of the `div`'s you are searching for might be queued up in the server and not appended to the DOM yet?

Comment: @MattSpinks yes that is precisely it

Comment: You could always set a flag and then reset it once you click the button.

Comment: I guess it is just a matter of better design then, thought you could configure AJAX to not allow queueing or something similar

Comment: Could you create a client side queue? And instead of immediately checking for the div when you get the response from the server, add the item to the client side queue. Then maybe have a function that iterates through the client-side queue and does comparisons for each item in the queue against the DOM. If a match is found, remove it from the client-side queue and append it to the DOM. Set that function on a timer to run every 1 second, 3 seconds, etc. That way you have a continual comparison going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is to disable the button when it's clicked. You can then enable it again should you need to:

```
$('body').on('click', '#test_button', function(){

    $('#test_button').prop('disabled', true);

    $.post('get_test_div/',function(response){
        //The following if is ignored if there are uncompleted queued POSTs
        if($('#test_div').length < 1){
            $('body').append(response);
        }

        // re-enables the button
        $('#test_button').prop('disabled', false);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "on" you can use "one".
This will allow only one click for the button.

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function( event ) {
  alert( "The " + event.type + " event happened!" );
});
```

Here is the link to documentation: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: This div can also be closed, also there are other types of divs, the button event needs to happen more than once

Answer (score 1):

It appears that items in your queue are searching for items that have not been added yet to your DOM (the items being searched for are stil in the queue). This is basically creating a deadlock. One possibility is a client-side queue...

1. Implement a client side queue. When you get a response from the server, instead of immediately checking the DOM for the div/id, just add the item (that you got from the server) to the client side queue.
2. Have a function that iterates through the client-side queue and does comparisons for each item in the queue against the DOM. If a match is found, remove that item from the client-side queue and append it to the DOM as you are doing now.
3. Set that function on a timer to run every 1 second, 3 seconds, etc. That way you have a continual comparison going on.